# Design Pattern: Client - Server

Tags: sockets, design-patterns, architecture, client-server, communication

i am going to implement a client - server application in java. Client and server communicate with each other via TCP. There is only one central server, who handles all Client messages.

I don't use RMI for the communication, they communicate with tcp-sockets and a client can communicate with another client through the server. That means that the server forwards messages from client A to client B.

Now im sitting here and try to figure out how to design the server application.

So the server is listen for incomming connections all the time. Thats fine. For every new client, that get connected to the server (dial-up), the server create a new Socket and i would use Threads to let them work concurrently.

Every User uses a client, and every client must be authenticated with a username and password.

Im searching for a design pattern to implement on the Server, that stores/handles the Socket connection to a client.

My first idea was to create a big Singleton object called ClientManager that contains a Map. So the Server could  call something like ClientManger.getSocketBy(username) to get the Socket of the desired User (Client).

This could solve the "forwarding" of messages from Client A to Client B.

For expample:
User A (Client A) would like to send a message to User B (Client B). So the server receives the message from User A (Client A) and call ClientManager.getSocketBy(User B) to get the communication socket to the User B, and then send the message through this Socket.

But this "design" on the server side seems to me to simple as it could be a good design for such a thing, and im missing something like Events, Observer etc.

Another possibility could be to throw an Event to the Thread that handles the User B socket connection instad of calling the Socket.send() method directly.

But there must be a better way ...

Is there a common way to implement something like this a design pattern that you can recommend? Im wondering how a instant messanger server would implement this?

By the way: im not implementing a instant messanger and the scalability is not the most important thing, since there are not 1000 of clients at the same time communicating with the server. A clean software design is more important for me.

Im implementing a own Protocol (xml based) for the communication. Is there a way/design pattern how to wrap a protocol in a object or is there nothing i could do (from the sofware architects view) excepted string / xml parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions I think.

The first is in regard to what "design pattern" to use for your routing.  You indicated what you were doing, but you didn't indicate what problem you are experiencing (or anticipate experiencing) other than to say it was too simple.  Patterns are common ways to solve common problems, but a program being too simple is not one I've seen a pattern for :)

The second question is about separating the implementation of your protocol from the clients that use it.  Now **that** is a good question and something you should definitely do.  You are going to want to create a Message object that exposes the fields (like To, From, Content, etc).  Your server needs to pass the raw xml data into some type of parser that acts as a Factory for the message objects.

```
Message msg = protocol.CreateMsg(byte[] xmlBuffer)
```

You can support additional protocols by assigning a different one to each TCP/IP Port or by starting with a default protocol and then having the client and server negotiate a different protocol.

EDIT1:

I would not map a socket to a User, to be honest.  I would abstract the way you communicate with a User into an object, perhaps Connection or Channel.  You would then subclass the Connection with TcpConnection or CorbaConnection or whatever.  Ideally you are doing something like:

```
string destUserId = msg.To;
User destUser = UserManager.Find(destUserId);
Connection conn = destUser.Connection;
if (conn != null)
   conn.Send(msg);
```

Note that there is no mention of the connection or the protocol implementation details.

Comment: So i dont want to run in a "anti pattern" ...
For example, the Singleton ClientManager which maps the User to a Socket sounds a little bit strange to me, to have such a central object, there must be a better way ... I really want to see (the code) how another project would implement something like that...

Comment: I added an edit, I do agree you do not want to tightly bind a socket to a user.

Comment: An abstraction to Connection is something that should be used definitely! 
Im not sure if a central class like UserManager is a good idea, but to be honest i don't know an alternative. Do you know any?

Should a User have a Connection or should a Connection have a User.
I mean, should i use Connection c = ConnectionManager.find(destUserId);
or the way you described UserManager.find(destUserId); Connection c = UserManager.find(destUserId).getConnection().
Maybe a mapping to a Connection would be better for security reason, since a User could contain info that should not be accessible this way.

Comment: It depends on your model.  Often Users exist even when there are no connections, so a User has a Connection (or a null ref if they are not connected).  Plus, if a connection is implemented as a socket, you may be able to support starting a dialog on one connection, and then (in the face of a network drop), that dialog to be picked up upon reconnect.  It depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

did you try the Service Locator pattern. But Java already implements what you are doing in its core, why "re-invent the wheel". You can use [CORBA](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/corba/corba.html) or one of the TCP/UDP based frameworks, like [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/) if you don't prefer RMI, and which will really help you build this distributed application of yours.

Comment: Thank you for your answere, but i can't use technologies like CORBA, RMI or ICE.

And my question is, how to design on the server side the mapping between User to his communication channel (a Socket, RMI, ICE, or whatever)